# How to access the elements inside an Object

Tags: java, arrays, string, jakarta-ee, arraylist

may I ask how to actually access the elements of an Object. My intention is to print out any object class, so I'm using

```
String x = ReflectionToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(obj)
```

with some style and modification, I'm able to make the "x" to become

```
[companyid=KLK,descp=KLK Kepong,reqbio=1,basedcountry=MY,processingfee=1.0]
```

but my problem come which is, IF there is another object (arraylist) inside that "obj" , the ReflectionToStringBuilder won't able to change that object to string and instead it become something like

```
[companyid=KLK,descp=KLK Kepong,banks=[my.sdinx.sdimngapi.peak.data.NP_CompaniesBanks@12d41a05]]
```

How can I actually access this

```
banks=[my.sdinx.sdimngapi.peak.data.NP_CompaniesBanks@12d41a05]
```

and change it to become like

```
[companyid=KLK,descp=KLK Kepong,banks=[bankid=MBB,descp=Maybank]]
```

I can't find a way to access it because my function accept Object so it won't know which custom class its accepting.

```
@Override
public void insertAuditLogDet(int recid, Object obj, Object obj2) throws 
SQLException { "processing the changed and insert into db" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `toString()` method in `NP_CompaniesBanks` class. That should solve it. I just tried it.

Comment: thanks for your answer..it works like a charm. hahahah thanks so much. i'm a newbie in java

Comment: yea, upvoted your post. like you haha savior of the day

Comment: Thanks! Enjoy your day

Answer (score 0):

Simple: you need to enhance your generic "dumper" method to do a "recursive" decent.

In other words: you apply your method **on** the fields that you find in your object.

There is nothing magic about this; it is "just work". But of course: complicated work; as you might have to apply certain heuristics; for example to turn a "list" into a string that uses [ to ] wrap around the elements of the list.